# Fetching parmeters from another html page GWT

Tags: java, gwt

How to assign and fetch parmeters from urls Like this

```
simple.com?userId=123456
```

I've tried `Window.Location.replace(url)` for assigning the parameters

so what can I use to fetch userId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried ??

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.getParameter("userId");//fetch parameter


com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location.assign(newURL);  //assign new url
```

before assigning URL to location  build your URL with `query parameters`